# SQL Server 2000 sp_xml_preparedocument - To get innerxml/innertext of a node

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2000

I have some data like at the bottom. I use SQL Server 2000 stored proc to process this data using sp_xml_preparedocument .

I would like to get the data within the node PartAuxiliaryID as it is below(the exact xml as it is, not the values or attribute) to a variable. What will be the best way to do that in stored proc using sp_xml_preparedocument

```
     <Info name="quoteNumber">962445</Info> 
     <Info name="shipSourceType">INTERNAL</Info>
```

---

```
  <Data> 
  <Item>
   <ItemID>
       <PartID>1234</PartID>
        <PartAuxiliaryID>
          <Info name="quoteNumber">962445</Info> 
           <Info name="shipSourceType">INTERNAL</Info> 
        </PartAuxiliaryID>
   </ItemID>
  </Item></Data>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

### Option 1

```
DECLARE @xmlData varchar(3000)
SET  @xmlData = '<Data> 
      <Item>
       <ItemID>
           <PartID>1234</PartID>
            <PartAuxiliaryID>
              <Info name="quoteNumber">962445</Info> 
               <Info name="shipSourceType">INTERNAL</Info> 
            </PartAuxiliaryID>
       </ItemID>
      </Item></Data>'

DECLARE @idoc int, @intRet int
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(1000)
EXEC @intRet= sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlData

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Data/Item/ItemID/PartAuxiliaryID')
WITH (PartAuxiliaryID varchar(2000) '@mp:xmltext')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--will get the following 

    <PartAuxiliaryID><Info name="quoteNumber">962445</Info><Info name="shipSourceType">INTERNAL</Info></PartAuxiliaryID>
```

### Option 2

```
DECLARE @xmlData varchar(3000)
SET  @xmlData = '<Data> 
      <Item>
       <ItemID>
           <PartID>1234</PartID>
            <PartAuxiliaryID>
              <Info name="quoteNumber">962445</Info> 
               <Info name="shipSourceType">INTERNAL</Info> 
            </PartAuxiliaryID>
       </ItemID>
      </Item></Data>'

DECLARE @idoc int, @intRet int
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(1000)
EXEC @intRet= sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlData

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Data/Item/ItemID/PartAuxiliaryID/Info')
WITH (PartAuxiliaryID varchar(2000) '@mp:xmltext')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

---

will get the following as two rows

```
   <Info name="quoteNumber">962445</Info>
   <Info name="shipSourceType">INTERNAL</Info>\
```